# Ionic Android app can't connect to local IP address

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am running my android app with `ionic cordova run android`, and doing a HTTP get to a local ip address:

```
this.http.get('http://192.168.2.124:8080')
  .pipe(map((response: any) => {
    alert(response);
    return response;
  }),
  catchError(map((error: Response | any) => {
    alert(error);
    console.error('API error: ', error);
    return error;
})));
```

However, nothing happens at all, no errors either.

Note:

- replacing the host with something I deployed on the cloud works just fine;
- using the phone's web browser to navigate to that endpoint *also works*.

I'm lost: is there a android or ionic configuration I'm missing to allow this?

Thank you

Comment: which android version you are trying.. what is the cloud URL .. just share domain name

Comment: is your local server and your mobile device  are on same network?